# The property "DataContext" does not exist in the "http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" namespace

Tags: wpf, xaml, resharper

I'm using a DesignTime `DataContext` inside of my `WPF Styles` to get full `IntelliSense` support.

```
<ResourceDictionary 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:alarm="clr-namespace:Foo.Alarm;assembly=HtCore"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem" d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance alarm:HtAlarmBase}">

    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

But the `Designer` `highlights` it and says:

> The property "DataContext" does not exist in the "http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" namespace

[image: error]

Is there a solution to hide this "error message"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could try:

```
<Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
    <d:Style.DataContext>
        <x:Type Type="alarm:HtAlarmBase" />
    </d:Style.DataContext>
</Style>
```

I don't really follow where you're headed with this though.

I would usually provide a design time datacontext for a whole view, including data for the treeview items. Without that, I wouldn't have any treeview items at all to show in the designer.

Comment: Thanks! You're the man! The "error" is gone!  I don't know exactly what you want to tell me. I don't see any difference in the Designer if I use your or my solution.

Comment: You presumably have some other way of telling the treeview it has  items. Presumably by binding to a collection of data. I would mock the whole view's datacontext at design time. That allows a variety of data and only one point of change. Shrug, Working = good.

Answer (score 7):

Personally, I had a similar error where it was complaining about Style not existing and I just had to switch `xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"` to `xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2010"` for it to compile again.

Comment: you're a life saver, thank you for posting this solution

Answer (score 0):

Do you have this line in your code?

```
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
```

If yes, try to clean (build > clean) your solution.

Comment: Have a look, I have updated my question with a complete  ResourceDictionary`. I had already added these namespaces.

Comment: There is some bug with the XAML stuff in Visual Studio. I alternate between having this error and not without making any changes. It's maddening. And yes, I have that line.